# Spring Tool suite maven error

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to both Maven and Spring.Following window comes everytime I try to create a new Maven project in Spring too suite.And when clicked finish 2nd window shows up.If canceled project structure ends up like shown in 3rd pic.Which is not what I should have to continue the beginner level spring tutorial.I've searched a lot but nothing was found helpful.My STS vesrion is 3.7.3.OS is ubuntu 14.04.I had installed maven.But uninstalled it in order to find a solution for this.But none.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pics are those warning windows .pom.xml
    `
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.infiniteskills.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>`

Comment: If this a vanilla and fresh STS distribution that you use? It looks like something is missing from the m2e projects maybe. Can you try this with a fresh STS installation, downloaded from https://spring.io/tools, running on a JDK8? If that continues to fail, I would recommend to file an issue at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS (attach a sample project or steps how to reproduce).

Comment: Thanks @MartinLippert  .Either Re-installing STS didn't work until I deleted /home/{usrname}/.m2 directory.Now it works fine.(-24hours of my life)

Comment: Sorry to hear about the pain this caused, but glad to hear that you got it solved.